# Java Google Drive download performance issue

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, google-drive-api

I have a performance problem with downloading some files from Google Drive.

The following code is executed in 4 parallel threads with different files.

```
serverfile = _drive.files().get(fileid).execute();
outstream = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(tempPath.getPath());

Files.Get request = _drive.files().get(serverfile.getId());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outstream);
```

I also tried a different implementation

```
serverfile = _drive.files().get(fileid).execute();
outstream = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(tempPath.getPath());

URL url = new URL(serverfile.getDownloadUrl());
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), outstream);
connection.disconnect();
```

This code results in "250%-300%" CPU load on my Quadcore Macbook Pro.
If I try a similar task with the dropbox api there is a much much lower CPU load.

Is there anything I can optimize to drastically reduce the CPU load?

One thing I found out is that it correlates with the download speed. I have a 100Mbit/s Internet connection and if i throttle the speed to e.g. 2 MBit/s the CPU usage is below 10%.

Comment: Can you clarify which of the two code samples uses the 250%-300% CPU load?

Comment: both are consuming the same amount.

Comment: How large are the files you are downloading? Is it lots of small files or a few big ones?

Comment: I used a mixed fileset so the size of the files is between a few kB and 200MB. And it doesn't make any difference if I only use big ones or small ones.

Answer (score -1):

You could try downloading the media using plain old Java, thus bypassing the Google library. Do a `files.get()` to fetch the File object. Then use its `downloadUrl` property to fetch the media using a simple Java http request.

Comment: I think I did this in the second code snippet. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: my bad, I didn't read snippet two. Version two is pure Java fetching https, so can't be optimised any further.